# robocopy is giving unequal number of directories but same number of files?

Tags: robocopy

When running robocopy I am experiencing the following. Can you correct/explain what is happening, please?

1. I get an extra directory under the total column and 1 skipped directory. Yet the number of files in total and copied columns are the same?. Note the number of bytes is also the same.
2. One of my directories appears to copy all but hangs up in some kind of a loop necessitating a restart of robocopy. I am never confident that the copy is ok. How can I identify the problem?
3. Options listed in the log are different than those specified.

   robocopy "E:\mmarion.4" "D:\mmarion.4" /E /256 /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP /TEE

becomes

```
Options : *.* /256 /NS /NC /NDL /NFL /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /NP /R:1000000 /W:30
```

Thank you. MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 3: Even if you don't specify some options, the output tells you which options are getting applied. In the case you quoted, the following are defaults, so they appear in the output even though you didn't include them in your command.

```
/DCOPY:DA
/COPY:DAT
/R:1000000
/W:30
```

The other odd one is /S. You specified /E, and Robocopy reports both /E and /S when you do that. That's technically a bit misleading, because /S means "... but not empty ones", and /E means "... including empty ones", so it can't really be both at the same time. But if you think of /S as meaning "... non-empty subdirectories" and /E meaning "... both empty and non-empty subdirectories", then having /E expanded to both /S and /E is not unreasonable.

Comment: That was a good explanation of E/ and S/. I think I understand Robocopy now. My computer disks had data corruption which made its use very confusing. My copies are working well now, but I do notice that there is one directory listed in the total column which is listed as being skipped. That corresponds to the highest level directory which contains one or more subdirectories?